# In Malcolm in the Middle, why doesn't Lois buy boxer shorts for Malcolm?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, malcolm-in-the-middle

In [this scene](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7vyt1z) in *Malcolm in the Middle*, Malcom asks Lois to buy him boxer shorts and Lois refuses.

However, in other episodes, Reese is clearly wearing boxer shorts:

[image]

[image]

**Why did Lois refuse to buy boxers for Malcolm when she appears to have bought boxers for Reese?**

- Was Reese Lois' favorite son?
- Were they really that poor that only Reese can wear boxer shorts? The dad didn't wear boxers. Malcolm and Dewey didn't wear boxers. Francis was away in the military academy.
- Didn't she care that Malcolm would have resented Reese because she buys boxers for Reese but when Malcolm asks she says no?
- Did Lois and Malcolm become enemies in an episode I missed?
- At the end of the episode, Lois finds out Malcolm likes a girl. She says she said no to Malcolm wearing boxer shorts because he shouldn't be faking things like wearing boxers just to get a girl, especially since he is still in school. However, she gave this reason *after* she finds out about the girl, not before.

Please help. I think I might have missed an episode that explains Lois' decision.

Comment: something like this is not something that sitcoms would care about for continuity

Comment: Thank you. That crossed my mind. I remember reading somewhere that Frankie got tired of being in his briefs on TV - he wanted to be in boxers when he is on TV or not do the scene.  Then, the writers wrote the scene in the link above and the episode's plot as a dig on Frankie's comment and never showed him in underwear again.  I just wanted to check if I actually missed something on the show that explained Lois' decision.

Comment: I can't prove that this is the answer **in the show** but many mothers consider boxers to be a non-child underwear and do not want to buy them for their sons. When someone is old enough to go buy their own underwear, they can buy what they want. Reese is a year older; the mother may not feel Malcom is ready for boxers yet.

Comment: Your analysis sounds reasonable and in alignment with Lois' character. 
I'm beginning to think Lois' reason may have never been given in the show and it is up to the viewer to interpret. 
Thank you for the comment.